# Some SVN Repositories not working - 405

Tags: svn

I have 2 groups of repositories, `web` and `engineering`.  I setup `web` about 3 months ago and it works great, I'm trying to move `engineering` over to this same SVN server and I'm getting a `PROPFIND of /svn/engineering/main: 405 Method Not Allowed` error when I try to do a checkout.

I can checkout/commit for `/svn/web` just fine

**dav_svn.conf**

This is the only thing uncommented in this file....

```
  <Location /svn/web>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /var/svn-repos/web
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "SVN Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file
        Require valid-user
  </Location>
  <Location /svn/engineering>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /var/svn-repos/engineering
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "SVN Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file
        Require valid-user
  </Location>
```

**/var/svn-repos/**

```
drwxrwx--- 3 www-data subversion 4096 2010-06-11 11:57 engineering
drwxrwx--- 5 www-data subversion 4096 2010-04-07 15:41 web
```

**/var/svn-repos/web - WORKING**

```
drwxrwx--- 7 www-data subversion 4096 2010-04-07 16:50 site1.com
drwxrwx--- 7 www-data subversion 4096 2010-03-29 16:42 site2.com
drwxrwx--- 7 www-data subversion 4096 2010-03-31 12:52 site3.com
```

**/var/svn-repos/engineering - NOT WORKING**

```
drwxrwx--- 6 www-data subversion      4096 2010-06-11 11:56 main
```

Comment: What shows up in your Apache logs when you try to check out the engineering repo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remembering to restart apache is an important step... use this as a prime example of how to properly setup SVN

Answer (score 0):

I think the multiple Locations are confusing each other - or rather, the first one is working and hiding the second (you can prove this by putting Engineering before web and seeing if web still works).

You can expose multiple repos using a single Location:

```
<Location /svn/>
```

This will allow you to browse `http://website/svn/web` and `http://website/svn/engineering` fine. If you want to list them both when you enter `http://website/svn` then add

```
SVNListParentPath on
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing basically the same thing you are with my SVN server. Here is a relevant snippet from my SVN server's Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Location /webdev>
       DAV svn
       SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn/repos
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "WebDev SVN"
       AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
       AuthGroupFile /path/to/.htgroup
       Require group webdev
    </Location>
    <Location /appeng>
       DAV svn
       SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn_appeng/repos
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "AppEng SVN"
       AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
       AuthGroupFile /path/to/.htgroup
       Require group appeng
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps.